# Karoubi envelope of category free $A$-modules is equivalent to category of projective $A$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, modules, algebras

Suppose $A$ is an algebra. It's a theorem that the Karoubi envelope (aka idempotent completion) of the category of free $A$-modules is equivalent to the category of projective $A$-modules.

Is there a proof of this theorem? I've come up empty handed. Thanks.

**Edit:** Is this the idea? If $P$ is a projective module, it is a direct summand of a free module $F$, so there is a surjection $\pi\colon F\to P$. Being projective, there is a section $s\colon P\to F$ such that $\pi s=1_P$. It follows that $(s\pi)^2=s\pi s\pi=s\pi$ is idempotent, and $s\pi(F)=s(P)\cong P$.

So the equivalence is given by the functor $(F,e)\mapsto e(F)$. This functor is essentially surjective by the above. Also, $e(F)$ is projective since $F\cong e(F)\oplus (1-e)(F)$, so it's a direct summand of $F$.

Comment: Well, you surely know that any projective module is a direct summand of a free module. Use that fact.

Comment: @zhen Thanks, if you have a moment, do you mind taking a look at my attempt?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. However, you need to define your functor on morphisms and check that it is fully faithful.